# XCode debugger lldb breaks without error output but program works fine

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, lldb

I got a strange behavior recently in my project.
It uses Objective-C for the output but most of the core is C++11. The many C++ routines are as inline only inside a header. The App is communicating with a server via berkley sockets. Also the App is working perfectly fine in the simulator and on an actual device. My logs a okay and the APP acts as expected...
   ...As long as I do not use the XCode debugger.

The debugger breaks always into the same line of code where I send a keep alive. This is done by a second thread. If I comment out this line, it will stop at the next line. If I put a `return` direct at the begin of the method, it stop at the return (btw it is a inline method). If I comment out the call, it stops at the next place where I use the method. If I hit continue, the APP works as expected, until the next call occurs.
In the log window there is only one output (after my logs):

> (lldb)

I already tried cleaning my app ("~library/developer/xcode") and restart all. No effect.

Unfortunately I found no way to reproduce the problem with a small sample.

My question, has anyone face similar problems? Is there a way to get information what lldb caused to stop?

Comment: Try typing `thread info` at the lldb prompt, or `thread list`.  This will show you the "stop reason" for each thread.  e.g. if you hit a breakpoint, it will say that.  If I attach to a process which pauses it, it will say `SIGSTOP`.  I don't kno what yours will say but it may help to understand what is happening.

Comment: @This will come in handy next time :-) I found the reason and will answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem after I rearranged my code, because I thought it might be a corruption of the call stack.

It sounds embarrassing, but it was a breakpoint! The problem was, it was not visible. Everyone who debugs know the situation that setting a breakpoint in a line were you could not set a breakpoint, the breakpoint will slip to the next logical position. This position is afaik always within the method you are setting it.
With C++11 and inline method calling inline method, this rule seem not unbreakable any more. The breakpoint was not in valid code regions between definition and the first inline method. Depending of which method was compiled first the breakpoint seems to be moved in some regular code. Clear the app cache didn't eliminate the breakpoint. Unfortunately (and of course) lldb does not tell you that it breaks because of a breakpoint you set.

Jason Molenda wrote following as comment, which will help other facing similar problems, I added in my answer because not everyone reads the comments:

> Try typing thread info at the lldb prompt, or thread list. This will
>   show you the "stop reason" for each thread. e.g. if you hit a
>   breakpoint, it will say that. If I attach to a process which pauses
>   it, it will say SIGSTOP. I don't kno what yours will say but it may
>   help to understand what is happening.